# Javascript element visible in viewport WITHOUT margins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following JavaScript to determine wether an element is visible in the current viewport or not. However, this does not take margins and paddings into account.   Can someone help me to modify this to return true, if the 'real' element is visible so margins and paddings are ignored?

Actual JS:

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.visible = function (partial) {

            var $t = $(this),
                $w = $(window),
                viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
                viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
                _top = $t.offset().top,
                _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
                compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
                compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

            return compareBottom <= viewBottom && compareTop >= viewTop;
        };
    })(jQuery);

    var win = $(window);

    var allModifications = $(".animation-listener");

    //make all elements visible that are directly visible
    allModifications.each(function (i, el) {
        console.log("loaded js");
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
            el.find(".half-width-text").addClass("open");
        }
    });

    //make elements visible that get scrolled into the viewport
    win.scroll(function (event) {
        var current = 1;
        allModifications.each(function (i, el) {
            var el = $(el);
            if (el.visible(true)) {
                el.addClass("animate");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `height()` use `outerHeight(true)`. This method returns the current computed outer height (including padding, border, and optionally margin) for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the outer height of every matched element.

http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

Comment: thanks for the answer, works fine but i just discovered getBoundingClientRect() which works a little bit better for my use case:)

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect ` -- that is what vanilla JS does without jQuery. =)